# XML to JSON | Spring boot | Jackson

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, jackson

I am working on a Springboot project and fetching data from Rest API. The response is in XML format and I am facing difficulty while converting it to JSON

**XML Response:**

```
<StoreInfo>
    <Store Number="1" NCPDPID="0411"/>
    <Store Number="3" NCPDPID="1132"/>
    <Store Number="4" NCPDPID="0407"/>
</StoreInfo>
```

The **JSON classes** I've created are:

```
public class IDResponse {

  private List<IDInfo> StoreInfo;
}

public class IDInfo {

  private List<Store> Store;
}

public class Store {

  private Integer Number;
  private String ID;
}
```

**Code to fetch and convert:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl,
            HttpMethod.GET, entity,
            String.class);

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
responseData = xmlMapper.readValue(response, IDInfo.class);
```

The **exception** I am getting:

- Method threw
  'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException'
  exception.
- Unrecognized field "Store" (class
  com.walmart.datamodel.location.IDResponse), not marked as ignorable

How to fix this?

Comment: `xmlMapper.readValue(response, IDInfo.class);`? Shouldn't it be `IDResponse`

Comment: @Turo, i tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The uppercase names shouldn't be used in the Java classes.
Number and Id are attributes so you should use Annotatiaons to guide jackson:

Root

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "StoreInfo")
public class IDResponse {


    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Store")
    @JacksonXmlCData
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Store> storeInfo;

    public List<Store> getStoreInfo() {
        return storeInfo;
    }

    public void setStoreInfo(List<Store> storeInfo) {
        this.storeInfo = storeInfo;
    }

}
```

Store Element

```
public class Store {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Number")
    private Integer number;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="NCPDPID")
    private String id;

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

IDInfo-class isn't needed.